# Swagger-UI not appearing properly

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

Why does my Swagger UI look different?

***This is what I have:***

[image]

***This is what I would like to have:***

[image]

In order to get Swagger-UI working, all i did was download the project(https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui), take all the contents in the dist folder and put it in the webapp folder of my dynamic web project. After doing this, I updated the index.html to point to my swagger.json. After this was done, I was able to see the first picture shown. However, the large execute button is not all that appealing :( How do i get my swagger page to look like the second picture shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first image is **Swagger UI ver. 3.x** or **4.x** (the curent version). The second image is **Swagger UI ver. 2** (old version, no longer developed).

If you want to use version 2 for some reason, you can download it from the `2.x` branch of the Swagger UI repository:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/2.x

Answer (score 0):

This is just the new look and feel of Swagger-UI from version 3. Just check their [FAQ](https://swagger.io/new-ui-faq/):

> **Hey, what happened to the UI?! I liked it much better in Swagger-X!**
>
> We took the the best of the existing projects, freshened things up and
>   voila! We’re likely to make more changes in the upcoming weeks, and
>   definitely more when we support the next version of the spec.
>
> **But I want the old look’n’feel!**
>
> That’s the great thing about the new projects – if you want to modify
>   the UI to suit your needs that’s a lot easier now.